# Cannot retrieve home url with custom queries

Tags: query, homepage

This is just driving me crazy. I cannot get wp to return the home page/url link. I have tried various combinations of

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) ?>
<?php echo esc_url( bloginfo( 'url' ) ) ?>
<?php echo home_url() ?>
```

But they all return the current page. In this case a page with attached queries.

Now I should mention that 1. I am not using the loop. I have not yet got to that stage though I did write it in to test this problem. 2. I have registered custom search queries.

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "search";
    $aVars[] = 'special';
    return $aVars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

The problem only seems to occur in search.php when these custom queries are in use. As you have probably guessed the returned home url is always .../wp-install/?search=foo&special=bar.

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Any of those should work, though the middle one is deprecated. Post your code in context. I can't tell what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

`home_url()` uses `get_home_url()` which in turn uses `get_option( 'home' )` to retrieve the home url. The code in `get_option()` includes this:

```
// If home is not set use siteurl.
if ( 'home' == $option && '' == $value )
    return get_option( 'siteurl' );
```

I didn't unwind all the previous code in the function, but it seems likely that under some circumstances `get_option( 'siteurl' )` does not match `home_url()`. Apparently, you found one of those circumstances. Try using `site_url()` in this case.

Comment: I ended up stepping through with the debugger (Don't know I didn't do it earlier) and found the problem. It ended up being a script set for the wrong id.

Comment: If you have the time, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so others can learn from it and so the question will have an answer.